# Getting started with stack on Windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to learn how to use stack to build Haskell project. I run from a command line:

```
stack new helloworld  new-template
cd helloworld  
stack build
```

I get

> Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages.
>   Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?

Any idea? I am on Windows.

Comment: What happens if you try another project template? E.g. `stack new helloworld simple`.

Comment: I get the same  thing

Comment: What is the output of `stack new helloworld  new-template`? Maybe somehow you're not cd'ing into the helloworld directory properly? Are there files in the helloworld directory?

Comment: What's your `stack --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your stack version with `stack upgrade`, you might be using some outdated or unstable version.